# issue in installing gazenbo on ubuntu 20.0.4 using terminal

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

line:wget  https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -o- | sudo apt-key add -

gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. `-o-` should be `-O -`.

```
wget https://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

`-o` writes the log output to a file, not the downloaded content. And by setting `-o -` you basically redirect the log output back to stdout.